# Using ArrayLists in Programs Java

Tags: java, input, arraylist

I want to use an ArrayList to use the Hailstone Sequence (http://plus.maths.org/content/mathematical-mysteries-hailstone-sequences) in a method and use that method to print out all the steps after the user inputs there number. This is what I have now:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getHailstonSequence(int n){
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(n);
    while(n != 1){
        if(n%2 == 0){
            System.out.print(n + " is even so I take half ");
            n = n/2;
            System.out.println(n);
        } else{
            System.out.print(n + " is odd so I make 3n+1 ");
            n = (n*3)+1;
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
    return getHailstonSequence(n);
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your number?");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Thanks!

Sorry for any misunderstanding.

What I'm trying to do is to create a program the number from the user and then displays the Hailstone sequence for that number. The exercise is suppose to use an Arraylist. 
Again sorry for any misunderstanding, I didn't mean to get anyone annoyed.

Comment: What's your question? We're not here to look over every line and guess what's wrong.

Comment: How you're planning to store an infinite sequence of numbers into an ArrayList is beyond me.

Comment: i don't see you calling your method getHailstonSequence from main. Again method getHailstonSequence you used recursion which seems to go in infinite loop.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Are you sure it's infinite?  :P

Comment: @DavidWallace According to the description from the link posted in the question, yes, but I have to admit that I didn't spot the `n != 1` guard condition in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your number?");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> result =  getHailstonSequence(n);
    System.out.println(result);
  }

  public static ArrayList<Integer> getHailstonSequence(int n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(n);
    while (n != 1) {
      if (n % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.print(n + " is even so I take half ");
        n = n / 2;
        System.out.println(n);
      }

      else {
        System.out.print(n + " is odd so I make 3n+1 ");
        n = (n * 3) + 1;
        System.out.println(n);
      }
      numbers.add(n);
    }
    return numbers;
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks about right, but you're dumping code without explanation - how should OP understand what was actually the problem with her code?